librdkafka producer configuration to control connection towards Kafka broker
Which configuration parameter controls the number of connections the librdkafka producer opens toward the kafka broker?
I use librdkafka for producing the message into the kafka. I discovered it uses only one connection toward brokers to produce a batch of messages. With one connection throughput is limited, I have requirement to produce thousands of messages per second.
Along with multiple connections, I need to preserve the order of the messages.
Note: I have configured batching-related parameters. My main concerns on connections.
Did not find any relevant configuration from the internet? Shall I consider creating multiple producers per partition?
Any suggestion would help.

If you want to preserve the order of messages do not go with multiple partitions and multiple producers to single partition. Because message order is preserved only along the partition not across the partitions.Also using multiple producers to single partition may not be consistent in case of message retries.
You can create only one producer handle using rd_kafka_new() API call at a time.
If your major concern is increasing throughput try to increase batch size.Also try some benchmarks suitable to your need to find best batch size.
Refer below docs;-
https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines
https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kafka-performance/
